# How long will shredded carrots keep?

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime

How long will carrots that I've shredded in the food processor stay good in the fridge?  Also what's the best way to store them?

Comment: I've never tried storing shredded carrots for a long time, but for cut up carrots, I store 'em in water, as the issue is they dehyrate quickly; you'll just have to dry 'em off before use.

Comment: Why would you not just shred when you need them?  Whole carrots will last must longer.  As Joe says - they will dehydrate quickly.

Answer (score 6):

According to the website [StillTasty](http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/16703), fresh, raw whole or cut up carrots will last 2 to 3 weeks in the fridge.

I would think that it would be a shorter time (1 week) for shredded carrots.  I'd store them in a container with a tight sealing lid, or in a plastic bag with the air squeezed out.

Answer (score 0):

I have carrots (from different sources) consistently lasting a month IF:
-They are whole, unpeeled, with no cuts
-Are stored inside a resealable bag that you can easily squeeze the excess air out of to minimize dehydration.

I have no firm experience on storing shredded, but you get a bit of an idea how long it might last by by how quickly it will go bad in a salad (a day or two). So as @Mark said, stored properly, you could probably only hope for a week.

Side-note, if you were looking to prolong the life of shredded carrot even more, you may be able to freeze it if it's in a sealed container, but I've not seen anyone do that personally, nor can I find anything online suggesting it works well. Might be worth the experiment though.

Comment: My small carrot cubes last for months in the freezer. They DO get a different texture, though. Because I fry them as a veggie-base for sauces anyway, that is all right with me. With shredded for Salad, you will have to test :).

Comment: @Layna Oh good to know. I really need to start putting date labels on everything.